# Set id and get id of inflated view?

Tags: java, android, view

I have to inflate the group of items in a listview and i need to find inflated view  anywhere  in the program .
    May I know how to find the view.
    How to set id and get id of inflated listview. 
    Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you talking about the adapter you use for a ListView?

Comment: Some code of what you  already have would certainly help

Answer (score 0):

In the Adapter of your list view

```
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View vi = convertView;
                if (convertView == null)
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newlistrow, null);
//Access your inflated layout using vi 
                 TextView sometextview= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textview); // sometextview
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you don't find views in a list view. The adapter behind the list view will pass you the view plus the underlying position of your data that you need to render via the getView method.

To answer your question of how to get or set id of inflated view you should call getId or setId on the inflated view.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()

```
View myView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.list_item_punch_log, null);
myView.setId(android.R.id.button1);
int id = myView.getId();
```

However doing this and finding views in a list view is a very **dangerous** act as it will cause some really funny behaviors on the listview. Maybe you can tell us what you are trying to do and we can guide you from there.

Comment: i am doing drag and drop concepts in listview ... i need to find the position while dragging the contents towards the listview before drop so that i can drop at a particular position where i  need

Comment: Its not going to be simple to drag and drop in a list view, if its not a lot of records you might consider using linear layout instead. Do look at this implementation though.. https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview